# Background Task - Translating a string based on user language

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I got universal app and the background task as separate project in my solution. 
I want to translate few lines in my background task depending on which language is used. Translating an app is easy because I just have subfolders for each language I will support and Resources.resw for each of them. But is there similar way to translate strings in background task? If not, is it possible and what's the best way? I tried to do it like in the app but it doesn't work

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
tileTextAttributes[0].InnerText = loader.GetString("test");
```

Comment: Are you asking to translate strings that you do not have entries for in any resource files? Like some kind of translation service?

Comment: No, I can create Resource file for this. In the app I got folder Strings and subfolders  for each language containing resource files. If I use ResourceLoader without any attribute it uses "Resources.resw" as default. I ask if is there a way that I will just put it in folders and use it like in the app or I have to check what language is used and load specific resource file for each language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question a bit late but I found exactly what I needed and it's super easy to do, because it works just like in an app.
I was using old way to localize data in the background task so it didn't work but once I've tried the proper command for W8.1 it worked like a charm.

Even if I have resource files in Shared/Strings/(folders representing language) in my main project in the solution, it works.

```
ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("key");
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Look into databinding. Instead of hardcoding the string like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Bonjour");
```

You could do:

```
Console.WriteLine({{Greeting.French}});
```

Greeting.English will be placed in a resource file along with Greeting.French